# How to start the Speclj tutorial?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, speclj

Inspired by [this coding kata](http://vimeo.com/65902219) I'd like to try the Clojure language.

After installing `lein` on my Ubuntu box, I wanted to use `speclj` for testing, so I went to the [official tutorial page](http://speclj.com/tutorial/step1), where I was told to simply execute `lein new speclj change-counter` to create my new project.

However, it seems to me that Leiningen thinks that my project name is "speclj" instead of "change-counter", so instead of having `src/change-counter/core.clj` I have `src/speclj/core.clj`.

What am I missing here? (`~/.lein` is empty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install lein by following the instructions in lein's README (as the tutorial you linked instructs)? I wouldn't be surprised to find that the version in your package manager is defective in some way, and it's almost certainly outdated. I don't know how lein templates are distributed, but I think a fresh lein install will magically have the one you're looking for, whereas an install from apt is probably static.

Comment: You are right, the current Ubuntu's `apt-get` was downloading an obsolete version. After removing that and downloading the `lein` script manually (as per instructions found in the README) the generated project structure seems to be OK. Thank you for your help.